# A/C dripping water onto exhaust

Tags: chevrolet, exhaust

I have a Chevelle 1970 w/ 427
The A/C drips water onto exhaust pipes up close to the engine.
Will that harm pipes when Hot??

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it's not going to hurt the exhaust for the most part. It could over time cause an issue with corrosion.

If the water you're talking about is what is coming out of the A/C box (on the firewall), you can most likely divert this by adding a small drain hose.

I'm not sure if those A/C boxes have a drain nipple, but most likely they have something there. Just attach a small flexible tube which will divert the water to below header level. Just run the tubing out of the way so it doesn't get cooked by the header.

If this is water dripping off the cold side going into the A/C box, you can wrap this line with some type of waterproof insulation. This will prevent water condensation on the tubing, which is where the water comes from in the first place.

BTW: I'm digging the ride! My first car was a 72' Chevelle which came with a 307, but I later put a 402 BBC in it out of a Monte. I still have a huge fondness in my heart for them :o)